# How to pass in a file name that contains a set of value and an int that says how many values are in the file. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

So basically im stuck on how to pass in a file name that contains a set of value and an int that informs the program how many values are in the file from the command line.

like I want to be able to do $> ./program file.txt 8

8 would be how many values are in the file.txt.

what would the code look like for that in C++

heres what I have so far but its nowhere near working :(

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream file;
    int size;
    int arr[size],val;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        arr[i] = val ;
    }
```

Comment: Examine `argc` and `argv`. You'll find `file.txt` and `8` there.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that command line parameters can be accessed via `argc` and `argv`. That's they are for.

Comment: ok I understand that now, but then how do I read that into an array like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: One post - one question, please. If you need help reading file contents into an array, ask another question.